# Get instance of same Java application if it is already running

Tags: java, singleton, mutual-exclusion

Is it possible to check if a Java application is already running and if it is, get an instance of it?
Say i have a jar that the first time it's clicked it opens a frame, and every time after that (until it's closed), it gets that frame and adds an object to it. This also needs to work without the main application having a close() method so the application will work again when reopened if it stops responding or it has been closed with task manager.

Comment: Have you checked the links in the "Related" section, on the right hand side of this page?

Comment: Yeah, I've found a few methods that can check if the app is already running. But i'm also asking for 2 extra methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java applications works on different process.

So is not so easy to interact between two different process (already running application and the new one).

What you can do is find a inter process communication mechanism and use it.
Typical [inter process communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) use files or a common database.

You can store the id of the current main thread executing your java app.

If a new process starts check if there is an already running application. 
If yes, you can use the same (or a new one) inter process communication system to send information that the main process should update. Then the secondary process kill itself.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had to get count and PID of running instance in JAVA on Linux. Just thought I would post my solution in case it could help someone in the future. (I have been helped so much in the past, I figured I should pay back a little).
Switch return to lngPidOfrunning for PID of other instance rather than count.

```
public long checkIsAlreadyRunning(){
    //Check if app is already running
     long lngCountOfInstances = 0; //Use this to hold how many already running
     String strProcessName = "appNameToCheckFor";
     //If it is required to also capture app running from within NetBeans, remove the .jar
     System.out.println("ps -ef|grep " + strProcessName);
     try{
         long lngPid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();//PID of this instance of the application
         long lngPidOfRunning = 0; //Holder for PID of already running instance
         System.out.println(lngPid+""); //Only for verification
         
         Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
         String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ps -ef|grep " + strProcessName };
         Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);

         delay_ms(2);//found I needed small delay to ensure buffer was ready
         
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
         
         String strLineIn;
         StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();
         String strProcessId = "";
         while ((strLineIn = reader.readLine()) != null) {                   
            if(!strLineIn.contains("grep") && !strLineIn.contains(String.valueOf(lngPid))) {//ignore is PID is current, or line contais grep 
                strOutput.append(strLineIn + "\r\n");//Only here for debuging
                lngCountOfInstances++;
            }
         }
         reader.close(); //always close the reader
         String strReturn = removeDuplicates(strOutput.toString()," "); // remove duplicate spaces frm reteun
         String[] strArray = strReturn.split(" ");
         if(strArray.length>2){lngPidOfRunning = isLong(strArray[1]);}//Aray index 1 will be PID, isLong checks if valid long and if yes, retunrs long, esle 0;
         System.out.println(lngPidOfRunning + " --> " + strReturn); //Only here for debuging
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
         err(ex.getMessage(), ex); //remove this, I use funtion to log messages and stacktraces to file
     }
     //return lngPidOfrunning; //Use this is you would like to use the PID to bring running instance to front
     return lngCountOfInstances; //use this if you just want to get count of running instances
}

private long isLong(String strValue){
        if(NumberUtils.isParsable(strValue)){
            return Long.parseLong(strValue);
        }
        return 0; 
}
```